# Cant find Regex to get part of a String

Tags: regex

I am searching for a Regex to get the value in Clamps after the fourth comma ("2") from this String

```
"showDetails("S1","72.00","0.00","62.00","2","15","859");"
```

Comment: I wouldn't, I'd `split` it using perl, and just get the 5th array element.

Comment: Now I am checking for "S1" written before first comma with this RegEx: `(?:\G(?!\A)|\"S1)(?:[^,]+,){4}"\K[^"]+`

Comment: How can I check for `showDetails("S1` because it doesnt work if I just add the text to the RegEx.?

Comment: OK I got it now! Thank you anway `(?:showDetails\("S1)(?:[^,]+,){4}"\K[^"]+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Merely for academic purposes**](https://regex101.com/r/sdgbgx/3/) (ugly as hell):

```
\((?:[^,]+,){4}"\K[^"]+
```

... or just split on the `,` and use the corresponding array like `arr[4]`